# Expression of direction of magnetic field induced by a current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

In order to find the direction of a magnetic field B induced by a current I we use the right hand rule but is there a mathematical expression for the right hand rule ?

Comment: Mathematically, it's built in to the definition of the cross product. If your question is why the cross product is defined according to the right hand rule, you should probably ask on Mathematics Stack Exchange. This Wiki page is probably relevant:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)

Comment: Its not because of the definition of the cross product because the curl isn't even a real cross product. Its because of the definition of curl.

Comment: You are thinking of the right hand rule for the lorentz force

Comment: In a sense the right hand rule is "built into" the curl operator as well. Regardless, the cross product is sufficient in this case because of the Biot-Savart law.

Comment: Yes you're correct, you could analyse biot savart actually to determine this. However I think fundamentally its because of the curl. However the curl of a vector field is not always perpendicular to that vector field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnetic field around a long straight wire is given by
$$B=\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}$$
where the directions of $B$, $I$ and $r$ are related by the right-hand rule.

[image]
<sub>(image from [Hyperphysics - Magnetic Field of Current](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magcur.html))</sub>

You can replace the right-hand rule by using
[vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) ($\vec{B}$, $\vec{I}$, $\vec{r}$)
and the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Cross_product) ($\times$).
$$\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_0}{2\pi r^2}\vec{I}\times\vec{r}$$

Comment: why in the denominator you have r^2?

Comment: @MissMulan One $r$ in the denominator cancels with the $\vec{r}$.
So you get $\frac{1}{r}\hat{r}$ (where $\hat{r}$ is a vector of length $1$).

Comment: $\vec{r} = \hat r |\vec{r}|$ which then cancels with $\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|^2}$ to become $\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it comes from the fact that a current produces a curl in the B field.

$\nabla × \vec{B} = \mu_{0} \vec{J}$

If you look at how the curl of a vector field is defined, you will be able to understand why the right hand rule works

Another intuitive way of describing this in a way more familiar with you would be stokes theorem.

$\int \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl}$

Using stokes theorem

$\iint (\nabla × \vec{B}) \cdot \vec{da}$

If there is a curl in the B  field pointing out of the page, ( corresponding to the current out of the page ), then stokes theorem says that this surface integral is positive as da and curl(b) are in the same direction .

But for the line integral to be positive, $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{dl}$  must be in the same direction,  and because dl is clockwise ( as per the definition of stokes theorem), $\vec{B}$ must be clockwise

(P.s obviously not rigorous that b and dl are always parralel, just that on average they are for the line integral to be positive, but you get the idea)